# How to access Seafile server in a virtual machine through IPtables?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-server, seafile-server, fail2ban

I have installed [Seafile-server](http://www.seafile.com/en/download/) `3.0.4 64bit` on a Ubuntu-server `14.04` with default ports settings (*i.e.* `8000`, `8082`, `10001`, `12001`) but fail to access the instance with the client.

### Infrastructure

The `Ubuntu-server` is running as a KVM machine on a `Gentoo` host.

#### Iptables rules

After some time I add the [following `Iptables` rules](ftp://ftp.linux-magazin.de/pub/listings/ubuntu-user.com/19/Seafile/Listing01.txt) to the host machine (`gentoo`), that seems to match the `Seafile`'s requirements:

```
#Iptables-Rules for Seafile
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8000,8082,10001,12001 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A output -p tcp -m multiport --sports 8000,8082,10001,12001 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

However I'm still unable to connect even with `telnet` to the seafile-server either from Internet or the host machine.

**Update:** issue might be related to `fail2ban`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using NAT to link my virtual machine to my host, I had to edit the rules as follow to get it to work:

```bash
#Iptables-Rules for Seafile
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 10001 -j DNAT --to 192.168.8.8:10001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 12001 -j DNAT --to 192.168.8.8:12001
```

#### References

- [Linux Firewall Tutorial: IPTables Tables, Chains, Rules Fundamentals](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/)